# Does GRE Tunneling "really" hide your main IP?

Tags: ip, tunneling

As we all know, setting up a [GRE Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation) is nice to hide your main ip under a dedicated server. My question is, is it really hidden? Is there a way a malicious user could somehow find your main ip through the GRE Tunnel? How about, your main IP being public on the internet? Isn't it still susceptible to bots and brute forces and ddos's. No IP address is really 100% hidden is it?

Comment: Try to sniff a GRE packet with wireshark and see what info can you read from it. If you are able to find out your IP address out of it then an attacker can too. Usually it is not necessary that a packet will always contain your IP address. for eg: If you are behind a NAT, then your private IP will be replaced by the router with a public IP in router's NAT table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through a GRE or other VPN tunnel does in fact obfuscate your IP address on the internet, provided the tunnel is acting as your default gateway and no other gateways are specified in your routing table.

When this is done, the normal means of gleaning one's IP address such as checking netstat/connection information, checking server logs, or querying it through whatever protocol will reveal only the VPN IP address.  Your "real" IP address should not leak at all through the tunnel under normal circumstances.

However, this is not the be all and end all of obfuscating your IP address.  Some client side applications may detect and send your real IP address to the server as well (although typically this will be a local IP address and not useful for an attack, per RFC1918).  Some javascript on web sites might contain an element that attempts to maliciously pass on your real IP address.  So, there are many caveats here.

Also, of significant note is that governments and private investigators armed with subpoenas will probably be able to easily track you despite use of a tunnel.  This due to their access to privileged locations on the internet, and ability to even subpoena the VPN provider.  From a technical standpoint, they can correlate traffic sent from the VPN IP to traffic sent back over it, and determine your real IP.   Or they can just get it by subpoenaing the ISP etc for logs.  Thus part of the reason Tor exists.

Comment: Oh no worries about government subpoenas. I just have a gameserver IP that needs to be behind a GRE tunnel. I'm using a ddos filtered IP on that GRE tunnel so it prevents any harm to my gameserver. Okay, that's good to know that my real IP will not leak through. And the only javascript that I use is a websocket connection with the ip from the gre tunnel so I should be fine there. Thank u Herring.

Comment: Remember that GRE is an unencrypted tunnel protocol.

Comment: @forest Aside from having a privileged place on the internet, think NSA secret-room at AT&T's datacenters style as highlighted in the last paragraph here, how would an unencrypted tunnel help you resolve the user's identity?

Comment: @HerringboneCat It doesn't. I just mentioned that because it's a salient piece of information since most people think VPN means encrypted.